# Average distance between points of lower dimensional simplices in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, integration, na.numerical-analysis

**Notation:** *By a simplex, we mean the convex hull of a finite set of distinct points in $\mathbb R^n$, which are called the vertices of the simplex. $\mathcal H^n$ will denote the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.*

**Question:** Let $S$ and $T$ be two (not necessarily disjoint) simplices in $\mathbb R^N$ with vertices $x_1, \dots, x_n$; $y_1, \dots, y_m$, where $2 \leq n, m \leq N$. What is the average distance between points of $S$ and $T$? In other words, how can one compute the integral

$$\frac{1}{\mathcal H^n (S) \mathcal H^m (T)} \int_{T} \int_{S} |x - y| \, d\mathcal H^n (x) \, d\mathcal H^m (y)$$

explicitly in terms of the vertices $x_i, y_j$? This seems like a linear, finite dimensional problem so there may be an explicit solution.

**Remark:** The motivation for this problem was a numerical problem - given a representation of a domain by a set of polytopes, how can we compute explicitly the average distance between points in the domain? The computation reduces to computing the above integral over pairs of simplices.

Comment: it is by no means "linear"

Comment: Your "simplices" are what is commonly called polytopes. Even the calculation of the volume of a polytope is a nontrivial problem, solved by [Lawrence](https://www.ams.org/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2.pdf) for simple polytopes. One can possibly use results/methods of [Haase](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312095v2) to extend Lawrence's result to all polytopes. As for an explicit expression of the average distance between polytopes, this seems way too hard for MO (if at all possible to do), especially if the distance is Euclidean.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Nope, the OP's simplices are, indeed, simplices (if they degenerate, the requested measure is $0$). The explicit formula is out of question, of course, but the question what to do if one desperately needs to compute that integral reasonably fast and with decent precision remains.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I see. Do you think an explicit formula for the case of triangles in $\mathbb R^2$ is possible at least? This was the original setting of the numerical problem.

Comment: @fedja : So, are you saying that, if e.g. $n=2$ and the points are the vertices of the unit square, then the convex hull of this set of points is a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex)??

Comment: @IosifPinelis Note the restrictions on the number of vertices in terms of the ambient dimension the OP imposed and especially the dimensions of the Hausdorff measures with respect to which the integration is performed. So, yes, the square is a degenerate 3D simplex and from the viewpoint of the 3D Hausdorff measure, it is just as good as the empty set, so this case presents no trouble :-). I'm not arguing with you about the definition of a simplex in general, just attracting your attention to the "small print" in the setup :lol:

Comment: @fedja : (i) What "small print" are you referring to? Even in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, $n$ distinct points are not in general the vertices of a simplex. (ii) I have never seen the phrase "degenerate simplex" anywhere in the existing literature; have you? This seems to be just a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK, OK. Let's just drop this side discussion, admit for the public record that you are right and I'm wrong, and try to figure out the actual question, which, I hope, we understand in the same way: given two triangles in $\mathbb R^2$ with non-empty interiors, how to compute the average distance fast with given precision? :-).

Comment: @fedja : (i) I think the matter here is not of just someone or something being right or wrong. It is, I think, the matter of saying "Nope" concerning just terminology when one certainly seems to know it is a "Yeah" for (almost) everyone. (ii) I do not think numerics in the case of triangles is a problem; see the latest addition to my answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis (ii) I can also quickly "output" a number for any integration request and claim it to be an approximate answer. The question is *what* is the *guaranteed precision* of the output and *how it is guaranteed*. What does Mathematica say about it? I have never seen it to tell me anything to that extent and without that part such outputs are hardly any better than wild guesses. In other words, what is the exact algorithm behind that computation?

Comment: @fedja : As shown in my answer, here we have a double integral, with simple affine limits, of an elementary (even if a multi-term) function. It is straightforward to bound such a function with any prescribed degree of accuracy on small rectangles, using (say) the [interval method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). One can also use other numerical integration methods. Also, I think that, for such a relatively simple and tame integrand, Mathematica's NIntegrate is very good.

Comment: @fedja : In fact, the quadruple integral reduces to just an ordinary one, as it is now shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that an explicit expression exists.

Even the calculation of the volume of a polytope is a nontrivial problem, solved by [Lawrence](https://www.ams.org/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2.pdf) for simple polytopes. One can possibly use results/methods of [Haase](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312095v2) to extend Lawrence's result to all polytopes. As for an explicit expression of the average distance between polytopes, this seems way too hard for MO (if at all possible to do), especially if the distance is Euclidean

Even if $n=2=m$ and $S$ and $T$ are the following specific triangles:
$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\colon0\le x\le1,0\le y\le1-x\}$$
and
$$T=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2\colon2\le u\le4,1\le v\le1+u/2\},$$
Mathematica has been unable to find the average Euclidean distance working on the integral

`Integrate[Sqrt[(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x},  {u, 2, 4}, {v, 1, 1 + u/2}]`

for over 20 min. **Update:** Eventually, in this specific case Mathematica output a long expression, occupying more than a page.

This suggests that, even if there is an explicit expression of the average Euclidean distance for triangles $S$ and $T$ on a plane, it will probably be hard to analyze, perhaps harder to analyze than just the definition of the average distance -- and then such an explicit expression would probably be of no use.

---

As for numerical calculation, in the case of triangles in $\mathbb R^2$ we just have a quadruple integral with very simply expressed affine limits of integration, which easily reduces to an **ordinary integral**:

[image]

So, it is straightforward (but a bit tedious) to compute the integral in question, using (say) the [interval method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). One can also use other numerical integration methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer. I am very surprised that even the triangles in $\mathbb R^2$ case is this complicated.

Comment: @NateRiver : You are very welcome. Even for triangles on the plane, it is a quadruple integral, whose completely specified version took Mathematica about half an hour to compute. So, it was actually a bit surprising to me that this quadruple integral in general can be reduced to an ordinary integral.